# Uber API affiliate program revenue is only available for US?

Tags: uber-api, affiliate

Ref: [Intro to Affiliate Program](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/introduction)

> The Uber API Affiliate Program allows you to earn rewards for referring new US-based Uber users. You can earn $5 USD for every new US-based Uber user you refer. We want our affiliates to get rewarded for all the new riders you refer.

If I understand the above correctly, only people in the **US** will benefit from the referral, and people outside the **US** will not?

Comment: Ehm, yes, so it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in the Uber affiliate program - it is currently available only for the people in the US. We do not have any announcements on any expansion of the affiliate program beyond the US. Please see our Affiliate FAQ for more information: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/faq